# gulp bourbon Can't import bourbon reference

Tags: node.js, gulp, bourbon, node-sass

I run  Gulp with  node-sass, node-bourbon, node-neat.
So far things can go well , can able complied sass file to css without error.
unless, I import bourbon and neat at the top of scss file. The error is occured.

```
"stream.js:94 throw er;// Unhandled stream error in pipe.
```

Error: stdin:1: file to import not found or unreadable: "bourbon"

same source but with grunt work well .  Any suggestion folk ?...

ps.  this is my gulpfile.js .-  https://gist.github.com/foonmod/71d8dee473226cdd46f6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the use of the `loadPath` property for gulp-sass, which should instead be `includePaths`.

Update your gulp-sass task in your Gist to look like this:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  gulp.src('sass/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      includePaths: require('node-bourbon').includePaths,
      style: 'compressed',
      quiet: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
});
```